# Joomla Installation stuck on white blank page

Tags: php, joomla, installation

I have put Joomla_3.8.3 folder under htdocs and run on browser.

http://localhost/Joomla/installation/index.php

It shows white blank page.

I have added this:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

on `PHP.ini` but it doesn't work.

Could you please help me how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Make sure error reporting is on and see if you get any errors.

Comment: what do you get when you go to the url [http://localhost/Joomla](http://localhost/Joomla) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you ask any Joomla Question you should mention the Joomla version you are using. Anyways first you need to get the errors and then only you can know how to rectify it. In Joomla main folder you will find a file named `configuration.php`. You need to change the file permission(775 or 777) in order to edit it.

next you need to change these param values to the below given values:

```
public $debug = '1';
public $error_reporting = 'maximum';
```

You need to then refresh the same page after saving this file. You cannot save until you change the file permissions. You will get some errors. You can then troubleshoot it.

Note: `To change the file permission on Windows you need to right click on the file and then chose Properties. Under Attributes you will find read only checked. Just uncheck Read Only and press Ok. This will make it writable.`

Comment: I couldn't find $debug = "1"; I found only this $registry->set('debug', 0);
  $registry->set('debug_lang', 0);  Thank you for help.

Comment: Change this to $registry->set('debug', 1);